# How do you get a whole, outward spitting curved edge in graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I don't very like the straight edge like

```
CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexSize -> Medium, GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding"]
```

[image]

I note an undocumented option `"CurvedEdge"`, which make me happy. But I don't know why it is sometimes **concave inwards** and sometimes **convex outwards**.

```
CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexSize -> Medium, GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedEdge"]
```

[image]

I can only control them one by one like this

```
CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexSize -> Medium, GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  Catenate[{Thread[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
       6 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 1} -> 
      GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -0.5}]], 
    Thread[{2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
       5 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 2} -> 
      GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> 0.5}]]}]]
```

[image]

I have to say I hardly can stand such dirty code. Is there a simpler way to implement it?

Comment: "But I don't know why it is sometimes concave inwards and sometimes convex outwards." Hm. The first diagram sort of suggests that `"CurvedEdge"` consistently produces arrow bent to the right. So it seems that this is the pattern that you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexSize -> Medium, GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding",
  EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[{{Medium, .8}}],
  EdgeShapeFunction -> (GraphElementData["CurvedEdge", 
      "Curvature" -> -Sign @ Det @  #[[{1, -1}]]][##] &)]
```

[image]

Use `"Curvature" -> - 1/2 Sign @ Det @  #[[{1, -1}]]` to get:

[image]

Replace `DihedralGroup[4]` with `DihedralGroup[6]` to get:

[image]

Comment: It is exactly what I want

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps not much better, but you could use patterns in the edge specification:

```
CayleyGraph[
  DihedralGroup[4], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexSize -> Medium, GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding", 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> {
    DirectedEdge[1|4|6|7, _] -> GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -0.5}],
    DirectedEdge[2|3|5|8, _] -> GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> 0.5}]
  }
]
```

[image: graph with desired curved edges]

Comment: Thank you, that does seem like a step forward, and I'll take it if I don't receive a more concise answer

Answer (score 3):

```
cg = CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4], 
     VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
     VertexSize -> Medium, 
     GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding",
     EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[{{Medium, .8}}]];
```

We can use [`PositivelyOrientedPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositivelyOrientedPoints.html) to detect the orientation of the edge routing coordinates to specify edge curvatures:

```
SetProperty[cg, EdgeShapeFunction -> (GraphElementData["CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> 
  If[PositivelyOrientedPoints[Prepend[#, Mean @ GraphEmbedding @ cg]], -1, 1]][##] &)]
```

[image]

Replace `-1` with `-1/2` and `1` with `1/2` in `If[...]` to get:

[image]

Replace `DihedralGroup[4]` with `DihedralGroup[6]` to get:

[image]